# How will you use Stack Overflow for Google Code Jam

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google

Today [Google announced](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/google-code-jam-returns.html) the [2009 Code Jam](http://code.google.com/codejam).

> This year, contestants will compete in
>   several 2½-hour online rounds,
>   attacking three to four difficult
>   algorithmic problems during each
>   round.

I wasn't a SO user during last years jam, but I have a feeling this years "difficult algorithmic problems" will be posted and solved by the hive-mind.

Has SO ruined Google's challenge?

Answer (score 5):

> Has SO ruined Google's challenge?

No, I don't think so.  Since Google Code Jam is a *timed* competition, I don't think it will be affected.

Other sites, like Project Euler, which aren't timed do get some attention on SO, but I think that only heightens awareness and interest in those sites.  I don't think it ruins them.  (I don't particularly like spoilers to other site's questions appearing on SO, but you don't have to read the answers.)

Comment: FYI the qualification round usually lasts for ~25 hours, enough time to ask on SO (During the next rounds, however, the vast majority of people can't even complete the 3 exercises within th 2.5 hours, let alone spend time on SO answering questions...).

Answer (score 3):

Let's face it, if anybody can solve the problem quickly, they're not going to give you their answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than answer the question on SO, don't you think they would just sign up for Code Jam?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... maybe I should try to find out the challenges in advance and keep an eye out for them.

I'm happy to notify the Code Jam organizers internally and see what they think if anyone wants me to.

Comment: If forum usage would be a rule violation, then **depending on the timing** I'm sure we could suppress such questions (when identified) for the critical (2ish hour?) period... or if it contravenes rule 12, indefinitely.